# How to convert a colored point cloud into a textured mesh?

Tags: mesh, texture-mapping, point-clouds, meshlab

I have a .ply file which contains a colored point cloud:

[image: frog point cloud]

I need to convert it as a textured mesh. I can create a blank mesh doing:

**Filters -> Point Set -> Surface Reconstruction: Poisson**

But the result is a white mesh

[image: frog mesh]

It seems that all the informations about the color go lost. Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you want vertex colors use Filters -> Sampling -> Vertex Attribute Transfer, click the appropriate boxes to transfer color, and select the appropriate source and target meshes.

If you want a texture, you first need UV coordinates - the easiest and messiest way for an arbitrary mesh is to do Filters -> Texture -> Parameterization: Trivial per triangle, then use Filters -> Texture -> Transfer: Vertex Attributes to Texture.  This can cause seams to appear.  For my messy meshes I use the Smart UV in Blender and export it out as a .obj, then import it into meshlab and use the aforementioned Transfer: Vertex Attributes to Texture filter.

Comment: Is there a way to do all this automatically? Maybe a python library or something similar?

Comment: I should have googled first. There is a python library (pymeshlab) which can do everything that meshlab can => you can write your own script